# How to aggregate column values into array after groupBy?

Tags: arrays, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I want to group by name and add color into array i have done following thing but it cant helped

```
val uid = flatten(collect_list($"color")).alias("color")
val df00=  df_a.groupBy($"name")
               .agg(color)
```

I have a dataframe with following values

```
    ---------------
    |name  |color |
    ---------------
    |gaurav| red  | 
    |harsh |black | 
    |nitin |yellow|  
    |gaurav|white | 
    |harsha|blue  |  
    ---------------
```

I want to group by name and store the color values into array using scala, to get a result like this:

```
    ----------------------
    |name  |   color     |
    ----------------------
    |gaurav| [red,white] | 
    |harsh | [black,blue]| 
    |nitin | [yellow]    | 
    ----------------------
```

Comment: What is the spark version that you are using?

Comment: @AnandSai I am using spark version 2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292

Comment: is `df.groupBy($"name").agg(collect_list($"color"))` not what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `collect_list`
The code is shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy($"name").agg(collect_list($"color").as("color_list")).show
```

Hope it helps!!